# How to run Stockfish on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, stockfish

I am trying to run stockfish on AWS lambda.

Here is my lambda function

```
    import os
import json
from stockfish import Stockfish

# The Stockfish binary is located at the root of your deployment package
stockfish_path = "/var/task/stockfish-ubuntu-x86-64-avx2"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    stockfish = Stockfish(path=stockfish_path)

    # Set the chess position or FEN notation as needed
    position = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"
    stockfish.set_fen_position(position)

    best_move = stockfish.get_best_move()

    response = {
        "best_move": best_move
    }

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
```

In my root I also have this stockfish binary I downloaded from stockfish.com.

I have deployed it to AWS lambda, but when I run the lambda I get this error:

```
[ERROR] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/lib64/libm'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 9, in lambda_handler
    stockfish = Stockfish(path=stockfish_path)
  File "/var/task/stockfish/models.py", line 57, in __init__
    self._stockfish_major_version: int = int(END RequestId: 304e4a19-2097-4770-92fa-8dc1bf9a680d
```

This is strange since it seems like an internal error with stockfish as opposed to something wrong with my code. I dont want to update the internal stockfish models that the error is referring to.

Comment: You can see from [the stockfish code](https://github.com/zhelyabuzhsky/stockfish/blob/eba2eb56460e8251b51c5231a1f47baae7d1ca8c/stockfish/models.py#L57) that it appears to be executing the supplied stockfish binary to determine its version number by parsing it from stdout. I'm guessing that it's not actually executing it at all or perhaps it does not have +x permissions so what's appearing in stdout is not actually the expected text including the version number.

Comment: Has x permissions

-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      40446240 Jun 30 19:19 stockfish-ubuntu-x86-64

Will see if its being executed. Thanks